# can I capture the submit event of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hunting all over the internet and I cannot find a straight answer.  I have a number of forms. Rather than assign unique ids to them all I want to capture the `submit` event and take the id out of `this`.  But I cannot capture the `submit` event.

Right now I've got:

```
$('#trainingRecords tr td form').on('submit', function(e) {
  alert('here'); // doesn't fire

  e.preventDefault();
  if (confirm("You're about to delete this training record. Sure?")) {
    $(this).submit();
  }
  return;
});
```

and the form code looks like:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" id="trainingRecords">

  @foreach ($personnel->trainingRecords as $record)

  <td width="30px">

    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'personnel/delete/' . $record->id]) !!}

    <button class="btn btn-xxs btn-danger" type="submit" class="deleteForm">

      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>

    </button>

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$record->id}}" /> {!! Form::close() !!}
  </td>
```

Why am I not capturing the submit event? 
What am I missing?

edited to add:  I tried adding an on('click') handler to the submit button.  That doesn't work either.  The form submits, but the function isn't being fired.

Comment: `Why am I not capturing the submit event? ` You are not capturing it because you are not listening to the `submit` event. How were you expecting to capture it?

Comment: Silly typo on my part. Fixed. Still not working.

Comment: Seems, you need both event bindings, bind to click to trigger confirm and submit and another to bind to submit to get the id, possibly on your exact selector you already have `$('#trainingRecords tr td form')`

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any `<form>` element in your html for that selector to match.  (Unless it's drawn by whatever code interprets `{!! Form::open()}` -- in which case there are lots of duplicate `<form>` elements, since you call that inside a loop.)

Comment: it's Laravel blade, and yes, hence trying to capture all forms inside the table id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schoolboy howler.  I was attaching the event listener to the DOM object and *then* creating the DOM object. I wrapped the event listener in a doc ready block and all was well. Except of course for using the submit event and then firing it, creating an endless loop. I changed it to click.

so this:

```
$('#trainingRecords tr td form').on('submit', function(e) {
  alert('here'); // doesn't fire

  e.preventDefault();
  if (confirm("You're about to delete this training record. Sure?")) {
    $(this).submit();
  }
  return;
});
```

became this:

```
$(function() {    
    $('.trainingDelete').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(confirm("You're about to delete this training record. Sure?")) {
            $(this).submit();
        }
        return;
    });
});
```

that's all it took.

Answer (score 2):

maybe like this

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
  //prevent form submission
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = this.id;
});
```

Comment: the page uses forms in other sections - I don't want to capture every form on the page

Comment: Just change the selector then $('form .yourFormsClass')

Comment: @gedq Then only bind it to the specific forms you want to capture the submit event from. Use an additional data attribute to mark all forms that need capturing `data-some-id`, then bind to those forms only.

Comment: I was hoping to do that by wrapping them in an id on the table. I can use the same cascade to apply a css rule to that cell so I know it's the right one.  Very puzzling. I'm braced for it being something stupid, I just wish I knew what it was